# Retrieve computer name and reg values then export to csv

Tags: powershell

I have created a PowerShell script that retrieves the following;

1. RegKey value "`Servername`"
2. Regkey value "`ServerListName`"
3. Regkey Value "`Version`"
4. Wmi-Object "`Computername`"

I would like to run this against a list of computers and export the values to a csv file or append the source csv file.

I can get the information to display on the screen but am having difficulty exporting and adding Titles for each of the returned results.

```
Clear-Host
$computers = Get-Content C:\Tanium.csv

foreach ($computer in $computers)
{ 

$RegKey ="Software\WOW6432Node\Tanium\Tanium Client"
 Cd hklm:\$RegKey 

Get-WMIObject Win32_ComputerSystem | Select-Object -ExpandProperty name 
Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path. -Name ServerName
Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path. -Name ServerNameList
Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path. -Name Version
}
```

I would like to either export or append the existing csv file displaying data as follows if possible;

```
ComputerName:      123455
Version:           7.098
ServerName:        1233456454
ServerNameList:    1233456454
```

Comment: What you show at the end is not a CSV, and nowhere do you actually get any data from other computers.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that PowerShell remoting is set up on all target computers:

```
$computers = Get-Content C:\Tanium.csv

Invoke-Command -Computer $computers { 
  $regKey = "HKLM:\Software\WOW6432Node\Tanium\Tanium Client"
  $regKeyValues = Get-ItemProperty -LiteralPath $regKey
  [pscustomobject] @{
    ComputerName = (Get-CimInstance Cim_ComputerSystem).Name
    Version = $regKeyValues.Version
    ServerName = $regKeyValues.ServerName
    ServerNameList = $regKeyValues. ServerNameList
  }
} | Export-Csv -Append -NoTypeInformation -Encoding Utf8 -LiteralPath out.csv
```

Note:

- I've switched from WMI to CIM cmdlets, given that CIM supersedes WMI in PSv3+.
- The output order of the custom objects doesn't necessarily reflect the input order of computer names (`$computers`).